# Remove the JavaScript object from array with checkbox in jquery table

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I'm working on project here I'm facing an issue: I have created jQuery table and on checkbox checked get all the values of specific row and push it into array now I want to remove each row record from array when I uncheck that row. I have written some script for remove but it doesn't work properly. And also tell me that is there any easy way to get data of specific row with checkbox in jQuery table.

**Script**

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/Student/GetFee",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ Class_Id: Class_Id }),
    success: function (list) {
        $("#view").html('');
        $.each(list, function (key, value) {
            var html = $(
                '<tr>' +
                    '<td>' + value.Id + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + value.FeeHeadName + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + value.SchoolName + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + value.ClassName + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + value.Amount + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + "<input type='text'  name='Paid' class='paid' onkeypress='paid(this)'/>" + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + "<input type='text' class='Discount' name='Discount' onkeypress='discount(this)'/>" + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + "<input type='text' class='NetAmount' name='NetAmount' />" + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + "<input type='checkbox' class='ckb'/>" + '</td>' +
                '</tr>');
            $("#view").append(html);
            html = '';
        });

        //pushing objects in array
        $('#view input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {                                             
            var row = $(this).closest('tr');
            var id = row.find('td:eq(0)').text();
            var fname = row.find('td:eq(1)').text();
            var sname = row.find('td:eq(2)').text();
            var cname = row.find('td:eq(3)').text();
            var amount = row.find('td:eq(4)').text();
            var paid = row.find($('.paid')).val();
            var discount = row.find($('.Discount')).val();
            var netAmount = row.find($('.NetAmount')).val();
                            
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                info.push({                                 
                    Fee_Id: id,
                    FeeHeadName: fname,
                    sname: sname,
                    cname: cname,
                    Amount: amount,
                    Paid: paid,
                    Discount: discount,
                    NetAmount: netAmount
                });                            
                console.log(info);
            }
            else {
                if ($(this).not(":checked")) {
                    var x = info.indexOf($(this).val());
                    info.splice(x, 1);
                    console.log(info);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

[image: Take a look of View]

Comment: you are looking for $(this).val() of the checkbox, but are you inserting it anywhere?

Comment: Your adding complex objects to your array, but only checking the value of the checkbox (which is a simple value) when trying to remove (they are not the same thing). But what are you really trying to do here. How is you array being used. If its to post, then why not build the array in the submit method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to loop inside the array and check which one have the id of the unchecked row

```
if ($(this).not(":checked")) {
    var indexToRemove = -1;

    for (var i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
        if (info[i].Fee_id == id) {
            indexToRemove = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (indexToRemove != -1) {
        info.splice(indexToRemove, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: it is not working i have put the alert after if (info[i].Fee_id == id) it doestn't show any alert

Comment: indexToRemove always come  -1 on every uncheck

Comment: The variable 'id' have value? The sentence: var row = $(this).closest('tr'); var id = row.find('td:eq(0)').text(); should be called before the uncheck method

Comment: I just put  info.splice(indexToRemove, 1)  in above if statement before the break and it worked for me, i have removed the 2nd if condition thanks for your help